# erro com ORM Mapping no doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-2

Estou mapeando o banco de dados com doctrine e estou tendo um problema.
Quando uso as Annotations da seguinte forma funciona perfeitamente:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="customer",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="email", columns={"email"})})
 */
class Customer {
    (atributos)...
}
```

Pois bem, quero utilizar o `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;` para que as `annotations` comecem com `ORM\` Exemplo:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="customer",uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="email", columns={"email"})})
 */
class Customer {
    (atributos)...
}
```

Porém desta forma o doctrine não está interpretando a classe como uma entidade válida...

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Class "Customer" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.'
```

Meu bootstrap.php está da seguinte forma

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$entidades = array("entity/");
$isDevMode = true;

// configurações de conexão.
$dbParams = array(
'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
'host'     => 'localhost',
'user'     => 'root',
'password' => 'pass',
'dbname'   => 'LojaVirtual',
'charset'  => 'UTF8'
);    
//setando as configurações definidas anteriormente
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($entidades, $isDevMode);   
//criando o Entity Manager com base nas configurações de dev e banco de dados
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Como está a organização de namespaces do seu projeto? Acredito que por algum motivo o Doctrine possa estar procurando a classe `ORM\Entity` dentro dos namespaces das suas entidades.

Comment: Realmente não sei se é isso, pois esse erro é comum quando esqueço de declara o `@Entity` no primeiro caso, já os namespaces ele está reconhecendo normalmente, o autoload está do jeito que o composer criou pro doctrine e só adcionei os classmap das entidades... Ele tem reconhecido todas as classes normalmente quando se trata do bootstrap.php ou do arquivo teste.php

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti nenhuma nova ideia?

Comment: consegue hospedar seu código em algum lugar para que eu possa testá-lo?

Comment: vou passar o projeto pro git

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti u.u uma parte do projeto não ta dando pra publicar, assim que conseguir eu aviso

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti https://github.com/rodrigoborth/LojaVirtual2

Comment: já consegui reproduzir. estou testando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver configurando o último parâmetro (`$useSimpleReaderAnnotation`) da chamada 
`createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration` como `false`:

```
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($entidades, $isDevMode, null, null, false);
```

A questão é que quando esse parâmetro é `true` (que é seu valor padrão), o Doctrine não entende quando as classes das anotações estão prefixadas com `@ORM` e falha na hora de levantar as informações das entidades.

[Essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755518/doctrine-2-no-metadata-classes-to-process-by-ormgenerate-repositories) ajuda a entender um pouco o problema.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, resolveu o problema. tava me matando pra resolver isso a alguns dias já.